# Why isn't this makefile working?

Tags: c++, makefile

So I got a project from Github named [Keylogger](https://github.com/TheFox/keylogger) for research. I tried using the makefile present in the project dir to compile the program. But today, only a day later, when I try to create it again, it gives me an error. Here is what I run and the result. First, I've also included the source code for the Makefile

Makefile source:

```
CC = gcc
CPP = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3
#CFLAGS = -I"C:\MinGW\include"
LDFLAGS = 
#LDFLAGS = -L"C:\MinGW\lib" -mwindows -s
MKDIR = mkdir
RM = rm -frv


.PHONY: all clean

all: build/test_keylogger.exe build/keylogger.exe

build/keylogger.exe: build/main.o build/functions.o
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

build/main.o: src/main.cpp src/main.h src/config.h build
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

build/functions.o: src/functions.cpp src/functions.h build
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

build/test_keylogger.exe: build/test_keylogger.o build/functions.o
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
    $@

build/test_keylogger.o: tests/test_keylogger.cpp build
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

build:
    $(MKDIR) "$@"

clean:
    $(RM) build/main.o build/functions.o build/keylogger.exe build/test_keylogger.o build/test_keylogger.exe
    @#$(RM) build
```

And this is the error I keep getting:

```
C:\Users\Kanishk\Documents\GitHub\keylogger>make
g++ -Wall -O3 -c tests/test_keylogger.cpp -o build/test_keylogger.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, g++ -Wall -O3 -c tests/test_keylogger.cpp -o
build/test_keylogger.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
makefile:30: recipe for target 'build/test_keylogger.o' failed
make: *** [build/test_keylogger.o] Error 2
```

Comment: is there a test_keylogger.cpp file in tests/ ?

Comment: Does the file `tests/test_keylogger.cpp` still exist?

Comment: Do you actually have gcc-mingw installed?

Comment: You said this worked once? Do you have `g++` available? Is the `tests/test_keylogger.cpp` file there?

Comment: "for research"​

Comment: Yes, the test_keylogger.cpp still exists in the tests folder. Where do I get g++ from? I have MingW installed. That's the reason the make command works on my terminal.

Comment: @kanishk singh you can also try replacing `CPP=g++` in the makefile by `CPP=[the name of your compiler's executable]`

Comment: @Caninonos I'm using the command prompt to compile this. I also have a Git Shell, which returns the same error as cmd.

Comment: I changed the compiler from g++ to sublime-text.exe and still nothing.

Comment: @kanishksingh i don't know sublime-text but after a quick google search, i looks more like an IDE than a compiler

Comment: I have devc++, what to I add to the makefile to make devc++ my compiler?

Comment: I got an error in the Dev C++ IDE environment upon checking the syntax of the make file. It says:

C:\Users\kanishk\Documents\GitHub\keylogger\g++.exe [Warning] 

C:\Users\kanishk\Documents\GitHub\keylogger\Makefile: linker input file unused because linking not done

Comment: @kanishksingh devc++ is also an IDE, you said you have mingw installed, it should include a compiler, a couple years ago it was mingw32, i haven't really touched windows since, maybe it's mingw64 now?

Comment: dec c++ has it's own compiler as well. I have minw32 as well. The make command is from mingw32 only. But it can't compile this shitt for some reason. I'm absolutely confused. just a few days back this was done all too easily. As if I'm using some wrong syntax or I uninstalled some vital program.

Answer (score 0):

`make` cannot find `g++` any more.

Path to `g++` is most likely expected to be in `PATH` environment variable.

You either erased `g++` or your `PATH` environment variable does not contain the directory where `g++` is.

You may also be be starting windows `cmd.exe` shell instead of using the Cygwin icon to launch `bash`. Cygwin launcher normally starts `bash` which sets up `PATH` for you. The fact that your command line includes backslashes `\` in the directory name implies that you run `cmd.exe`.